# Custom repository class in symfony 2 not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm new to symfony 2 and actually love it. Just sometimes I don't know if it is in the docs or just my self.

Since hours I try to get the repository class to work and been trough the questions and also the doctrine docs which alle didn't help me.

So all those links didn't help me

- [Symfony2s doctrine:generate:entities doesn't generate repo classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14115143/symfony2s-doctrinegenerateentities-doesnt-generate-repo-classes)
- [custom repository class in symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146461/custom-repository-class-in-symfony2)
- http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/book/doctrine/orm.html

Actually there isn't a lot I should do to accomplish the right result but I always get an error saying: **"Undefined method 'findAllOrderedByName'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! 500 Internal Server Error - BadMethodCallException"**

I think there is something wrong with my namespaces and or use statements, but I have no idea. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and maybe also what I should do to get it right? All I want is to get that method `findAllOrderedByName()` to work.

so here is what I have:

Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/Product.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{ 
    // all the code which was/is working
}
```

Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Entity/ProductRepository.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllOrderedByName()
    {
        return $this->getManager()
            ->createQuery(
                'SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
            )
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace Acme\StoreBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function showAction()
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        $products = $em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
            ->findAllOrderedByName();
        return $this->render('AcmeStoreBundle:Default:showAll.html.twig', array('products' => $products));
    }
}
```

Thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Have you cleared your cache since making the change?

Comment: @Qoop `rm -R ~/Projects/Symfony/app/cache` ?

Comment: Or `app/console cache:clear` / `app/console cache:clear --env=prod|test|dev` depending on your choice.

Comment: @Qoop thank you, I just did, but still the same error :(

Comment: How about these ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/a/15315838/1791606

Comment: @Qoop tried them all. still same error

Comment: What does get_class($em->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')) return in showAction?

Comment: @RoelHarbers it returns `Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository`

Comment: @caramba: It looks like your annotation isn't parsed at all. What AnnotationReader are you using? What does your doctrine: orm: mapping config look like?

Comment: @RoelHarbers Thanks! just figured it out the same time probably, it just took me hours.. (I started with this a month ago and didn't really remember that step..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for everyone who was helping. I figured it out, **IT WAS MYSELF** of course there was nothing wrong with symfony but much more with what I did:

After the command:

```
 php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/StoreBundle
```

I choose for

```
"Determine the format to use for the generated configuration." --> xml
```

And not annotation. So I had to change in my

```
~/Projects/Symfony/src/Acme/StoreBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/Product.orm.xml
```

file. the `<entity name="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product">` to

```
<entity
        name="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\Product"
        repository-class="Acme\StoreBundle\Entity\ProductRepository">
```

Comment: Yes, forgetting to tell Doctrine to use your repository class is a killer. Another thing that will make you tear your eyeballs out:  if you have caching enabled, disable it. I just spent a couple hours learning that lession.

Comment: Same goes for entities generated out of yml schema

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$products = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AcmeStoreBundle:Product')
        ->findAllOrderedByName();
```

and

```
public function findAllOrderedByName(){
    return $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
        'SELECT p FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p ORDER BY p.name ASC'
        )
        ->getResult();
}
```

You can also try different function name. Instead of findAllOrderedByName() choose for example findProducts().

Comment: Thank you. Still the same error. I've also tried with: `$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();` but it doesn't changes anything

Comment: Thanks again, I've tried with your updated answer, still the same error